# Would touching the dark mark work after polyjuice potion?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

I recently reread The Deathly Hallows, in which Hermione uses polyjuice potion to turn into Bellatrix Lestrange. I was wondering whether Hermione could have summoned Lord Voldemort by touching the Dark Mark. It is not the original mark after all.

Comment: My idea is we should think of it as a mask, highly complex yes, but still a mask. So probably no, Hermione wouldn't have been able to summon Voldemort, the same way I am not able to see in the night even if I wear a cat's mask. Of course this is only my opinion, I wasn't able to find any explanation from official sources.

Comment: Man, this is a great question. I have no idea. Some food for thought - would the Seven Potters (from the beginning of DH) have felt pain through Harry's scar? I'm inclined to agree with @NicolaBastianello that they would not. Another possibly relevant point is that when Harry took Goyle's potion, he didn't need his glasses (he adopted Goyle's good vision, his eyes didn't just change colour).

Comment: @luna That's a body-characteristic over a magical one though, like Moody's missing leg and eye. I'd presume that whilst the actual Dark Mark does transfer over the magic that is present in it does not.

Comment: I don't think the Dark Mark would've been used as a key to Malfoy Manor if the magic of it could be replicated by something as seemingly common as polyjuice potion.

Comment: @NicolaBastianello I don't know if your cat in the mask is the best evidence for your point. Bearing in mind, that when Harry uses the polyjuice potion in Chamber of Secrets to turn into Goyle, he actually loses his shortsightedness. Clearly the impersonator takes on the physical abilities of the impersonated (in this case, normal eyesight). However, whether that extends to physical characteristics that are not natural and were imposed upon a person's body (tattoos, dark marks etc.) is a moot point.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66812/does-the-polyjuice-potion-dark-mark-work refer this

Answer (score 1):

No it won't. The Dark Mark is linked to the person who belonged to the inner circle. It responds only to the actual member of the inner circle. Hermione, not being a part of it can't.

Comment: A reference, or a quote from a book or interview backing this up would go a long way.